# Connecting to my SSID force opening a browser window. How?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, browser

I'm aiming my clients to get a popup/browser display once they connect my Wifi.

Currently it s running with HostAPD.
You see my SSID in available wifi, no password.
Access only to my local web. No IP forwarding.

But Id love my clients to automatically have their browser opened (splash page in captive portal) when they join my SSID.
I dont want to make them pay or else... just display a splash !

I dont manage to do it with HostAPD.
SHould I get more luck with something like http://www.hotspotengine.com/ ?

I alread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118196/captive-portal-detection-popup-implementation

Answer (score 0):

Detecting captive portal and showing a pop-up is something done by the OS of the device connecting to your AP. There is nothing much you can do it at your AP to show pop-up.

Most iOS and new Windows devices would do that but its not consistent on Android.

I am assuming you have a captive portal working already.

If you have captive portal working then you will be able to set a landing/splash page in its configuration. The way captive portals works is that when a user connects to your wifi hotspot he/she will be redirected to this landing page when they try to browse.

Pop-up is basically a browser too so when captive portal is detected by the OS the pop-up will opened by the OS which will then try to goto a URL (defined by the OS). However as user login has not been authorized by the wifi hotspot yet, user will be instead redirected to the landing page defined by you in captive portal setting.

If you do not have a fully functional captive portal working then you can use any of these, [Coova Chilli](http://coova.org), [Chillispot](http://www.chillispot.org/), [WiFiDog](http://dev.wifidog.org/), [NoCatSplash](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nocatsplash/)

Quoted in order of functionality supported and ease of implementation.

Comment: Thanks @GetSplashed : yes it's done by the OS. I cannot do anything about the showing process, Ok. But when popup show happens, how its content is defined ? You see what I mean ? For instance, a restaurant captive portal asks for your secret number on your note, where this page is stored ? how the OS know the URL to display in the popup ? That s really my quest.

Comment: Ok I just updated my answer, take a look at it. It should get you going.